# Update HTML list from Android using Simperium

Tags: android, html, simperium

I'm new to using Simperium but I'm hoping it can accomplish what I need. Given that the site mainly has tutorials and samples for IOS, I thought it only best to seek help here.

I want to be able to edit and update an event list on my website that is just a simple html list with the event name and date. Is this possible with Simperium and if so, how would I go about doing this? If there were tutorials out there directed to Android I wouldn't have to ask this here but there isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do have a Simperium library for Android that is still under development but it should be able to suit your needs in its current state.

The best example out there is to check out how we used Simperium in WordPress for Android. I'm not sure how familiar you are with how Simperium works in general, but here goes:

The `SimperiumUtils` class shows how we start up and connect to Simperium. You could do something similar and replace the app name and key with your own: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/ui/notifications/utils/SimperiumUtils.java

The `Note` class is the object that is synced with Simperium in the notes bucket. You set up a schema in the class, and that's what is synced with Simperium: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/blob/develop/WordPress/src/main/java/org/wordpress/android/models/Note.java

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Since "SimpleNote" app uses simperium flawlessly in Android, isn't there documentation somewhere and how it's done? Also, the simperium-android github repository is a little confusing. How do I know which part is the library?

Comment: @Steve sorry, there's no documentation for the Android library yet. As it gets closer to a 1.0 release we will write some docs.

Comment: @Steve the library code is here: https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-android/tree/develop/Simperium